# Index of array with maximum length

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to get the index of the array with the longest length.
I have this array of arrays.

```
[
 [0,7,3],
 [1],
 [2,6,5,2,9],
 [1,2]
]
```

The desired outcome is **2** because it is the array with the maximum length.
I have this working code:

```
max_len = -1
index = -1

for i, feature in enumerate(features):
    if max_len < len(feature):
        max_len = len(feature)
        index = I

print(index)
```

I think that should be a one-liner or a much better and simpler way to do it.
Does anyone know a better way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like a python list, not a numpy array. You can use `l.index(max(l, key=len))` if `l` is your list.

Comment: This is not very efficient. You are iterating the list 2 times. One in `index()` call and other is in `max` call.

Comment: @ShipluMokaddim it is much more efficient than pulling from the `enumerate` iterator and calling a python `lambda` for each element. Time it yourself.

Comment: @timgeb - benchmarked both solutions with 1000 to 100_000 `lists` of length 4 to 1000. This solution is ~5x faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate` and `max` for this one:

```py
max_length_index, _ = max(enumerate(l), key=lambda index_and_lst  : len(index_and_lst[1]))
```

Comment: The key function expects one parameter

Comment: @timgeb Indeed, looks like I cannot use unrolling here.

Answer (score 0):

This is a one-liner:

```py
vals = [[0,7,3],[1],[2,6,5,2,9],[1,2]]
pd.Series(vals).apply(lambda x: len(x)).idxmax()
```

You could also do this without pandas:

```py
lens = [len(val) for val in vals]
print(lens.index(max(lens)))
```